# How to filter an array based on route in React.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, url, filter

I have an array of posts where I would like to use the values from the url or route to determine what I want to show in the array, something like a filter. For example, my selected post is 'www.mywebsite.com/chocolate' so in my route where I display my posts, I only display 'chocolate' and not all the other posts. Is there something I can do like this, where the result === 'chocolate':

```
const post = response.data.filter(({url}) => url === 'dynamic_variable_that_knows_what_the_current_url_is_with_the_value_of_chocolate');
```

Below is my code for App.js:

```
getData() {
    axios.get('/posts.json')
        .then(response => {
            //console.log(response);
            const post = response.data;
            const updatedPosts = post.map(post => {
                return {
                    ...post
                }
            });

            this.setState({
                posts: updatedPosts
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}

render() {

    return (
        <div className={classes.App}>
            <Layout>
              <Switch>
                <Route path="/food/:slug" exact render={(props) => this.state.posts.map(post => { return (<FullPost key={post.id} id={post.id} pathname="/:slug" {...props} />)} )} />
                <Route render={() => <h1>Whoops! What you're looking for isn't here anymore.</h1>} />
              </Switch>
            </Layout>
        </div>
     );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `props.match.params` to access the `slug` and filter later.

Consider following example from **Router 4** [documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Route).

```
<Route path="/user/:username" component={User}/>

const User = ({ match }) => {
  return <h1>Hello {match.params.username}!</h1>
}
```

In your case it will look similar to

```
const post = response.data.filter(url => url === this.props.match.params.slug);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it looks like I'm getting a 'Cannot read property 'params' of undefined though...

Comment: because you'd have to make sure `this` references your Component. Be careful how you call getData()

Comment: Thank you, I understand what you mean now. To help others I will clarify that because I was doing the filtering logic on the App.js level, there are no components to pass the props params to, I can't directly pass props from App.js to FullPost,js. So I created an intermediary component that filters the posts to which I can access props and pass props. So the flow would be like this. App.js contains the <Route> that loads the intermediary <FullPostSorter> (which has props) that loads the <FullPost> (which pulls in the props from FullPostSorter).